# Import/convert a 3d scan in blender

Tags: stl

I have a 3dscanner from Rodin that uses Captevia, this program can only save files as a CPV-file.
Blender doesn't recognize this file system, Is there an add-on or seperate software available that can turn any 3dfile format into an STL file?

Comment: According to the official site of Captevia it should be possible to export also in stl and obj. Anyway there's probably no addon that handles CPV files for Blender (None that I know of anyway). You can try MeshLab to resave the cpv file to something that blender can handle or you can try to import it via blender python using external library